# How can I collect data by sending the register as props to the child component using React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Using React Hook Form, when I want to collect data by sending register as props to child component to take input value from child component, it shows 'register is not a function' error.
How can I solve this?

```
const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);    
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
       <fieldset>
           <legend className='text-[#666666]' >Status</legend>
            {
              statusData.map(status => <CheckboxFilter register={register} key={status._id} status={status}/>)                           
            }
       </fieldset>
     </form>
```

here child

```
//CheckboxFilter component

const CheckboxFilter = ({ status, register }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <p className='text-[#858585] mt-2 text-[14px]' >
                <label htmlFor={status?.name} className='cursor-pointer' >
                    <input {...register("checkBoxData")} type="checkbox" name="status" id={status?.name} value={"status?.name"} /> {status?.name}
                </label>
            </p>
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sandbox here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-collect-data-by-sending-the-register-as-props-to-the-child-component-using-react-hook-form-n18kg3?file=/src/CheckboxFilter.jsx) and it works perfectly.

I took your code and only changed the CheckboxFilter component:

1. Removed the `name` property (`register` function returns the name of the input based in the string you pass to it as a parameter, you should not override it)
2. Removed the `value` property (that was making the value of the checkbox constant, because there wasn't onChange handler that was modifying it)
3. Changed `...register("checkBoxData")` to `...register(`checkBoxData${name}`)` so this way you can have every checkbox value individually in the form.

Anyway, if you want to have a different behaviour than what I have assumed, let me know and I will help.

-Ado

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the problem.
Can you tell me how to get the value of the checkbox as soon as it is clicked without clicking the submit button there?

Comment: Sure, you can use `watch` method from `useForm()` to subscribe to the checkbox value. [Watch - React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch/). You also could use the [`getValues` method](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/getvalues), it depends on what you want.

Comment: Hi @ARBurhan did you find my suggestion useful?

Comment: I'm sorry brother. I couldn't do that. How to send the true or false value that you are sending after clicking the submit button so that the checkbox is clicked? If you told me, I would have benefited.

Comment: Ok, so if I get it right, you want to get the value of the checkbox exactly after you check or uncheck it, without clicking the submit button. Is it ok?

Comment: I want to get the value as soon as checked and unchecked..